# Chef - Local variables within ruby_block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

First time using chef/ruby

```
buildNumber = String.new

ruby_block 'test' do
  block do
    def parse_xml
      buildNumber = "123"
    end

    parse_xml do
    end

    print "buildNumber is: " +buildNumber
  end
  action :run
end
```

I want the line `print "buildNumber is: " +buildNumber` to print out 123 and not blank, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that indentation intentional?

Comment: Is there a reason to use `parse_xml do ... end`? Why not just run `parse_xml`. What is `parse_xml` supposed to do? It's trying to set a variable (`buildNumber`) that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I put the whole thing in a begin-end block as follows and it worked.

```
buildNumber = String.new
    ruby_block 'test' do
      block do
      begin
    buildNumber = "123"
    end

    print "buildNumber is: " +buildNumber
      end
      action :run
    end
```